# S3 presigned url from api returned to aws contoller does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, c#-4.0, aws-lambda, pre-signed-url

I am creating S3 presigned URl in one of my mvc controllers and that is to be consumed by a python lambda. But getting below error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>There were headers present in the request which were not signed</Message>
    <HeadersNotSigned>x-amz-date</HeadersNotSigned>
    <RequestId>D7815D6EDC8BB6D0</RequestId>
    <HostId>jViPAaaoh+UQDQoMzB9QZXAFyIxgvw7sLr7+Otj4tJFukLkynf07B1Z81iYE8aJ4i+p0B+1Dmwc=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Tried allowing all actions on S3 bucket.

```
//This is how I am creating presigned URL
public string BuildPreSignedURL(string bucketName, string objectKey)
        {
            string urlString = string.Empty;
            IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
            try
            {
                GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = objectKey,                 
                    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(preSignedURLExpireTimeInMinutes),                
                };
                urlString = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return urlString;
        }

//Below is now it is returned from controller
string preSignedURL = preSignedBuilder.BuildPreSignedURL(bucketName, entityS3Key);
  return new RedirectResult(preSignedURL);
```

AWS lambda calling my api contoller should be able to download the file.

Comment: What happens if you try to use the pre-signed URL yourself, with a browser?  The problem may be related to how you ultimately use it, rather than the way you are initially generating it.

Comment: Yes if I open the pre-signed URl frlom my browser. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `C#`, but with `Python` we need to set also the "method" when we generate the presigned URL. In the example below it uses `get_object`.

```
s3_client = session.client('s3')
try:
    response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                        'Key': object_name},
                                                ExpiresIn=expiration)
except ClientError as e:
    logging.error(e)
    return None
```

Comment: my lambda in python calls an api endpoint using POST which in turn returns an presigned URl.